# HTML page source code has unexplained comments

Tags: html, database, drupal, blogs

I recently purchased a DRUPAL site and while examining the source code of index.php, I found a huge section of HTML code that is commented out.
I found the code in the database and I tried clearing the cache, but it still appears.

Does anyone knows how to delete it, or where the code is being generated?
I can't find it in the menu/articles/pages, or any other section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a lot possibilities, I'll list 2 obvious ones:

- custom modules: check the module page
- custom theme/template:check under theme folder to see if there is any file with `.tpl/php`

Also not sure what you mean "i found the code in the DB and I tried clearing the cache"
, clearing cache won't remove effect db.